# How can I house keep the connect.log for a specific period of time only in my kafka connector?

Tags: apache-kafka, log4j

I have a kafka connector setup in my machine, and it will generate a log in `kafka-path/logs/connect.log` every day. It also generate a patch of logs such as `connect.log.2022-06-15-1`, `connect.log.2022-06-15-2` at the end of the day.

Is there a option in kafka such that I can keep only 2 weeks of the logs only?

Comment: Add a max backup index of 14 https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/config/connect-log4j.properties#L29

Comment: Haven't personally tried it, but yes.

Comment: For kafka connector, you should add `log4j.appender.connectAppender.MaxBackupIndex=14` in `kafka/config/connect-log4j.properties`.